# Android change local configuration doesn't work

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I am building an application which comes in two languages, using a setting activity where the user can change the language. Once the user has selected any language, I want to save his/her choice so when the application is launched again, the new language will appear. I have done everything connected to layouts in different languages and different orientations.

#### My problem

when I launch the application, It always launches in the `English` language, although I print the locale language and the result is `Arabic`.

#### Hint

when the user changes the language from the setting activity, and he/she presses save, the application is working perfectly in the new language. Unfortunately, when restarting the application, it is not started in this new language.

#### My code

**Tags.java** - A class which contains but three strings:

```
public class Tags {
    public final static String LANGUAGE = "Language";
    public final static String ENGLISH_LANGUAGE = "en";
    public final static String ARABIC_LANGUAGE = "ar";
}
```

**Splash activity** - The activity where the application starts:

```
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
if (!someData.contains(Tags.LANGUAGE)) {
    editor.putString(Tags.LANGUAGE, Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    Locale locale = new Locale(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Setting.setLanguage(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
} else {
    String currentLanguage = someData.getString(Tags.LANGUAGE, Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    Setting.setLanguage(currentLanguage);
    Log.e("currnetLanPHone", Setting.getLanguage());
    if (currentLanguage.equalsIgnoreCase(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } else {
        Locale locale = new Locale(Tags.ARABIC_LANGUAGE);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
editor.commit();
```

It confuses me because as I explained before, the language of the application is changed and the new layouts are loading when I change the language from the `Setting activity`.

I am sure that you will ask me to give you the code of the `Setting activity` in order to compare what I have done in that activity with the splash activity. This code is as follows:

**Setting activity**

```
if (s_language.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("English")) {
    editor.putString(Tags.LANGUAGE, Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    Locale locale = new Locale(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Log.e("Inside", Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Setting.setLanguage(Tags.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE);
} else {
    editor.putString(Tags.LANGUAGE, Tags.ARABIC_LANGUAGE);
    Locale locale = new Locale(Tags.ARABIC_LANGUAGE);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Setting.setLanguage(Tags.ARABIC_LANGUAGE);
}
editor.commit();
```

The code is pretty simple, I used a spineer `s_language` from two values.

*A problem could be that, in the setting activity, when the user presses `save`, the `Setting` activity is finished. In the `splash` activity, I check for the language in the `oncreate` function, before continuing the activity and finishing it after doing a number of steps. I don't think that finishing the activity is the problem, but I just told you in order to make the image clear.*

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could You confirm that pref stored are valid and You get get valid language in splash activity?

Comment: @sandrstar I verified that and It is working perfectly.

Comment: So, on start do You observe some english strings on splash activity (with currnetLanPHone printed as arabic)? How have You detected that it started in English, not arabic?